# How can you replicate a chrome browser_action popup using firefox addon sdk?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm porting a chrome extension to firefox. I'm trying to create a button that shows a popup HTML just like chrome. This is what I have so far in the main `index.js`:

```
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var buttons = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

var manifest = require('manifest.json');

var url = function(path) {
    return self.data.url('../' + path); //get out of the "data" directory
};

var popupButton = buttons.ActionButton({
    id: "show-popup",
    label: manifest.browser_action.default_title,
    icon: {
    "16": url("icon16.png"),
    "32": url("icon32.png"),
    "64": url("icon64.png")
    },
    onClick: function(){
        //this doesn't work for debugging JS
        //tabs.open(url(manifest.browser_action.default_popup));

        //reload the content, like chrome, and show the popup
        popup.contentURL = 'about:blank';
        popup.contentURL = url(manifest.browser_action.default_popup);
        popup.show();
    }
});

var popup = panels.Panel({
    contentURL: url(manifest.browser_action.default_popup),
    position: popupButton
    //contentScriptFile: ... get from HTML?
});
```

The buttons shows the HTML, however, the javascript which chrome makes you include via `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>` tags doesn't appear to have access to `self.port`. Also, there seems to be no way to debug code in a panel. I've seen it suggested you open the HTML as a tab rather than a panel for debugging, but then it's running in a different environment and neither `self` nor [`addon`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24125980/1888983) are defined.

Unlike chrome, firefox wants you to give the javascript for the panel separately, using [**<strike>`contentScript`</strike>** `contentScriptFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35029914/1888983) as a `Panel` argument. One idea I had was to extract and remove all the `<script>` tags from the HTML, then give the remaining HTML to the panel and pass in the scripts separately. However, the panel wants a URL and not HTML. Also, it's starting to feel like too much hackery.

1. How can I replicate the chrome browser_action functionality in firefox? I would like to be able to use the same files in both chrome and firefox and not have a second build script which processes files depending on the target browser.
2. Is there a better way to debug a panel, like in chrome with right click and inspect?

Comment: you'll need to use a content script file to enable talk between the addon and the panel. If the js script is in the htm file, you could try saving it as a js file and use that as the content script. it should still access the dom elements. or create a content script as a link and look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts

Comment: @flapjack17 I could probably load and parse the html to extract the links to the js files to be used in `contentScriptFile`. However those scripts will still be referenced from the HTML. Is there a way I could pass HTML directly instead of a `contentURL`? Then I could strip the links dynamically.

Comment: I don't believe so. if you were to strip the js from the html in to a content script file it should still run as if it was embedded in the html.